# Changing '0's in a list to avoid divide by 0 errors

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Suppose I have a nested list: `{{2,0,3},{4,0,4},{0,0,9}}`. I would like to change all the `0` to `0.00001`, or some other small value, so that the final result is `{{2,0.00001,3},{4,0.00001,4},{0.00001,0.00001,9}}`

How would I go about doing so without using the `For` and `If` functions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems unlikely that changing zeroes to something very small is the most elegant solution here. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to divide two images to form another image. The images are greyscale, with pixel values ranging from 0 (black) to 1 (white). How do we handle division by a black pixel?

Comment: @flame What results do you want from `0/0` and `0/1` ?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a better solution is to allow the division by zero, but suppress the warning:

```
In[1]:= Quiet[1/{{2, 0, 3}, {4, 0, 4}, {0, 0, 9}}, Power::infy]
Out[1]= {{1/2,ComplexInfinity,1/3}, {1/4,ComplexInfinity,1/4}, {ComplexInfinity,ComplexInfinity,1/9}}
```

But I guess if you want to replace the `Integer` 0 with 0.00001, then you could try

```
In[2]:= {{2, 0, 3}, {4, 0, 4}, {0, 0, 9}} /. 0 -> 0.00001
       1/%
Out[2]= {{2,0.00001,3},{4,0.00001,4},{0.00001,0.00001,9}}
Out[3]= {{1/2,100000.,1/3},{1/4,100000.,1/4},{100000.,100000.,1/9}}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
{{2, 0, 3}, {4, 0, 4}, {0, 0, 9}} /. {0 -> 0.0001}
(*
-> {{2,0.0001,3},{4,0.0001,4},{0.0001,0.0001,9}}
*)
```

However, as @nomulous said, it's unlikely that this is the best way to achieve whatever it is you're after. So, what are you trying to do? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

EDIT: In your comment you mention that you're trying to divide images. Without seeing more code, I'd suggest something like this:

```
i1 = Image[ {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}]
i2 = Image[ RandomReal[1, {3, 3}]]
Image[Quiet[i2[[1]]/i1[[1]]] /. ComplexInfinity -> 1]
```

which extracts the list of data, divides, allowing division by zero to occur yielding `ComplexInfinity`, replaces `ComplexInfinity` by 1 (the maximum allowed) and then wraps `Image` around the resulting list.

Perhaps if you show more code it will be easier to suggest something better.